# Confirm same password with Zend_Filter_Input

Tags: validation, zend-framework, password-confirmation

ZF 1.11.3 here.

```
$validators = array(
    'pass1' => array('presence' => 'required'),
    'pass2' => array(array('Identical', true, 'token' => 'pass1'))
),

$input = new Zend_Filter_Input(array(), $validators, $this->_request->getParams());

if (!$input->isValid()) {
    var_dump($input->getMessages());
}
```

Using the code above, I get (firephp formatted, actually):

```
['pass2'] =>
array(
  ['notSame'] => 'The two given tokens do not match'
)
```

As you've might presume, that error shows up even if "pass1" and "pass2" contain the same string (it's basically a password confirmation form).

I cannot use Zend_Form or addValidator() (don't ask), so I must joggle with this syntax, which is why *I think* it doesn't work. I'm referring to `array(array('Identical', true, 'token' => 'pass1'))`. I've even tried `array(array('Identical', true, array('token' => 'pass1')))`, getting the same error. I don't seem to understand where those arrays are to be set.

Suggestions, corrections or "halp!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Zend_Filter_Input were to use the **context**, it would validate comparing to **the value of** `some_input_name`, not to **a string** like `some_input_name`. And because I don't use Zend_Form, it can't use context.

> Zend_Filter_Input not working with context but through of the Zend_Form_Element you can use context.

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10673

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `Zend_Valiate_*` you can't use `Zend_Filter_Input` because `Zend_Filter_Input` will try to create instances of the validators given in the array.

Furthermore I think your syntax is wrong. Look at this example from the manual:

```
$validators = array(
    'password' => array(
        'Identical',
        'fields' => array('password1', 'password2')
    )
);
```

Comment: I don't know where you got that example from, but I'm looking at the manual right now [and it's not there](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html). I **can** use Zend_Validate_*; I didn't say I couldn't. I just can't use the [(easier) syntax of addValidator()](http://www.wjgilmore.com/blog/entry/validating_identical_passwords_with_the_zend_framework). I've used Zend_Filter_Input before, but not the "Identical" one.

Comment: Ok, I've played a little in ZF's source and it seems that it validates my "pass2" input value (say "xxx") **to "pass1"**, not **the value of** "pass1". If I type "pass1" to the "pass2" text input, it works. How exactly does ZF know the the value of the token is a name of an input and not an actual value? The code is in Zend_Validate_Identical::isValid().